# Exception copying string into an array of strings from a Java Form using getText()

Tags: java, string, forms, swing, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` with the following Java code:

```
static String s[],t[],temp;

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    s[0]=jTextField2.getText();
    jTextField3.setText("The input string is: "+s[0]);
    temp=jTextField1.getText();
    t=temp.split(" ");
    jTextField3.setText("The input string is: "+t[0]);
}
```

This code keeps giving me `java.lang.NullPointerException`. What is wrong with my code???

I also tried this way:

```
static String s[],t[],temp;

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    temp=jTextField2.getText();
    s[0]=temp;
    jTextField3.setText("The input string is: "+s[0]);
    temp=jTextField1.getText();
    //t=temp.split(" ");
    //jTextField3.setText("The input string is: "+t[0]);
}
```

And also `jTextField3.setText("The input string is: "+t);` doesn't work with t declared just as static String t. in the text field it shows some exception again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int LENGTH = 10;
static String s[] = new String[LENGTH];
static String t[] = new String[LENGTH];
```

Comment: Oracle documentation is a good place to start http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: static String s[]=new String[20],t[][]=new String[20][20],temp;


This did the trick. Nobody will give more than 20 strings as input for the case I wanted.

Thanks a lot..!!!

Comment: Btw, as other users said, please take a look at ArrayList class.
You'll find that it is very easy to use, and it saves you to use much more memory than needed using standard arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring your array, but you're never initializing it, and so when you try to access the array items, for instance like so, `s[0]`, a NPE will be thrown since `s` is null.

You need to assign the array to an array object like so:

```
// SIZE is an int constant that is the size of the array you desire.
String[] s = new String[SIZE];
```

Side notes:

- You likely should not declare any of these variables as static, and doing so suggests that the program design could be improved.
- I have to wonder if you are using parallel arrays to hold your data. If so, consider creating a new class to hold each "row" of data's information, and then using an ArrayList of this type of class.

---

**Edit**
You state:

> But I dunno the size initially. Can I use String[temp.length];???

You could initialize your arrays to a large size, one that's likely to be larger than you expect to need, however an even better solution is to not use arrays at all (directly) but rather use ArrayLists which behave sort-of kind-of like arrays of variable size.